# Get NSData straight from AFNetworking, rather than letting it convert to UIImage

Tags: ios, afnetworking, nsdata, afnetworking-2

Is there a flag that would let me get NSData, rather than let AFNetworking convert my responseData into the corresponding data type(UIImage, NSString)?

Comment: This can be done, but how are you fetching the image? Are you using the UIKit extensions, or AFHTTPRequestOperationManager/AFHTTPRequestOperation?

Comment: AFHTTPRequestOperationManager

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `AFHTTPResponseSerializer` will return the raw `NSData`:

```
    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
    manager.responseSerializer = [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];

    [manager GET:... parameters:... 
         success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSData *responseObject) {} 
         failure:...];
```

Answer (score 0):

responseData in AFN means (id)  - AnyObject.

You could create another object. For example NSMutableArray.
than make `myArray = responseObject;`  - for example

Comment: I know I can cast it to whatever, but that won't change the actual data of the object.

Comment: No. You will get the same data. Just converted to what you need

Comment: So that doesn't help me

Comment: UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] init];
NSData *data = (NSData *)image;
// data will let me call methods on NSData, but if you look in the console data is actually a UIImage.  And if I call a method on data that doesn't exist on UIImage I'll get an exception.

Comment: Use UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];

Comment: Let me re-word my question.  I'll do later today, thanks for responding though