# From ASIHTTPRequest to AFNetworking

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking

I am following a tutorial about Multithreading from http://www.raywenderlich.com/4295/multithreading-and-grand-central-dispatch-on-ios-for-beginners-tutorial. In this tutorial ASIHTTPRequest is used and I see that AFNetworking has pretty much become the standard now.

I am trying to download a zip file using this block:

```
  __block ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:sourceURL];
    [request setCompletionBlock:^{
        NSLog(@"Zip file downloaded.");
        NSData *data = [request responseData];
        [self processZip:data sourceURL:sourceURL];        
    }];
```

How would I go about doing this in AFNetworking? Do I need to use something like this?

```
NSURLSessionConfiguration *configuration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
AFURLSessionManager *manager = [[AFURLSessionManager alloc] initWithSessionConfiguration:configuration];

NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://example.com/download.zip"];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:URL];

NSURLSessionDownloadTask *downloadTask = [manager downloadTaskWithRequest:request progress:nil destination:^NSURL *(NSURL *targetPath, NSURLResponse *response) {
    NSURL *documentsDirectoryURL = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomain:NSUserDomainMask appropriateForURL:nil create:NO error:nil];
    return [documentsDirectoryURL URLByAppendingPathComponent:[response suggestedFilename]];
} completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSURL *filePath, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"File downloaded to: %@", filePath);
}];
[downloadTask resume];
```

In the tutorial I need is to download as NSData though and in AFNetworking is is using NSURlResponse.

Any pointers on this would be great. thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would seriously go and look at Apple's documentation on NSURLSession. Before NSURLSession, configuring a simple upload/download task with NSURLConnection was a bit of a pain (to say the least), hence AFNetworking became very popular... and deservedly so.

But NSURLSession has fixed much of that and in general, it's a good idea to get to know the real API's versus a third party (and no disrespect intended towards AFNetworking).

The learning curve for NSURLSession has lowered so much that it is not much worse than learning AFNetworking... at least IMHO.

And to be more specific about your above question, I believe you only have to substitute the above AFURLSessionManager call with the equivalent NSURLSessionManager call.

Comment: Interesting, AFNetworking kinda grew on me over the years because of this exact issue. Never really had a go at the standard API's after that. Will definitely give that a try later

Comment: YEah I actually looked at sendAsynchronousRequest in NSURLRequest. Seems like all that wrapper is doing in ASIHTTPRequest is making it slightly easier to set what happens in a completion block or fail which can just as easily be done with if(!connectionError)...

Answer (score 1):

The AFNetworking part looks right I suppose. Just try that out and see if it works. In order to retrieve the NSData of the downloaded file you could just use the `contentsAtPath` method from `NSFileManager`.

Example:

```
completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSURL *filePath, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"File downloaded to: %@", filePath);
    NSString *path = [filePath path];
    NSData *data = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsAtPath:path]; 
}];
```

Comment: So it seems that by using AFNetworking you have to first save the file to the device instead of just the memory?

Comment: I think you could download directly to memory by using the correct response serializer for your request. Have a look at this question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24769103/get-nsdata-straight-from-afnetworking-rather-than-letting-it-convert-to-uiimage

In this particular case you wouldn't use a downloadTask though, since that method specifically downloads a file to the filesystem.