# How to implement Codable with AFNetworking

Tags: swift, objective-c, afnetworking, codable

I am working on a mix project of Swift and Objc, AFNetworking is implemented in it for network calls. I created swift file where I want to implement Codable model, but since AFNetworking is responding back in NSDictionary or id format response I am unable to use the decodable.
I need a way such that AFNetworking returns me NSData/Data format response object which I can directly use with decodable

Comment: Have you seen https://stackoverflow.com/a/24788682/5329717 ?

Comment: @Kamil.S yes but that didn't work. AFNetworking has evolved respect to that answer. But I managed to get a solution by serialisation. Although it doesn't feel like a good solution.

Answer (score 0):

Using the default `AFHTTPResponseSerializer` as your `responseSerializer`, you will get the response data in the second parameter of the `success` closure. You just need to type cast it as `Data`:

```
let manager = AFHTTPSessionManager()
manager.responseSerializer = AFHTTPResponseSerializer()
manager.get(urlString, parameters: nil, headers: nil, progress: nil, success: { task, object in
    guard let data = object as? Data else { return }
    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
    do {
        let decoded = try decoder.decode(MyType.self, from: data)
        print(decoded)
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
}, failure: { task, error in
    print(error)
})
```